# How to know if a file has been moved to the virtualstore?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

under window 7 and 8, if a file generated by the program is placed under the same path of the application executable files (by using 'Application.StartupPath' for example), windows will automatically move it to the 'virtualstore' folder.

For this situation, inside the program if I check the existence of the file using:
`if file.exists(application.startuppath & file)`, it will return `True` even though the file has been moved to the virtualstore.

For some users however, they somehow disable the file visualization, so the file will stay under the program folder. My question is, how do I know for sure which folder this file is under by code?

Edit:
the question is more like: how to check if a file exists under application folder, 'File.Exists' doesn't work well for this situation, as it always return True.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the VirtualStore location.
VirtualStore is a subfolder of `%localappdata%`(`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`). Then add the folder of your application to it (starting from `Program Files`), and the filename. Now check whether the file exists or not.